# Need a recommendation for managing a database link

Tags: databaselink

I want to make a package which needs to have a external database link.
But it is hard for me to have an idea about how to manage the database link.
I want the link to be connected as long as I use the package and there must be only one link and functions in the package use the link implicitly and the link should be reconnected if got disconnected.

Is it possible?